# use dojo tooltipDialog for every link in the page using parameters

Tags: tooltip, dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

anyone know how to open a tooltipDialog from extlib using parameters.

in csjs I find all links in a webapage and bind them to mouseover. using a key in the link I know which link is clicked, I want to send this key to the toolTipDialog so that I can use that to find the document and display document data in the tooltipDialog.

Currently the only way I have found to open a tooltip dialog is by using XSP.openTooltipDialog("tooltipid",'linkid') which does not seem to allow parameters.

any ideas how to resolve this

Comment: to open popups, look at dijit.popup API. It will calculate and set position 'around' a node - which would be your eventTarget in mouseover

Answer (score 1):

Hows this?

```
require(["dijit/TooltipDialog", "dijit/popup",
   "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/lang"],

     function(ready, TooltipDialog, popup, on, dom, lang){

        var myTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
            id: 'myTooltipDialog',
            style: "width: 300px;",
            contentTemplate: "<p>Key is: {key}</p>",
            content: 'empty',
            onMouseLeave: function(){
                popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
            },
            onOpen: function(pos) {
              this.set("content", lang.replace(this.contentTemplate, this.replaceObject));
            }
        });
                                                                      /
        query('a.hasSelectorClass').on('mouseover', function(){     // 
            myTooltipDialog.replaceObject = {                     //
                key : this.innerHTML // (inner text in anchor node)
            }
            popup.open({
                popup: myTooltipDialog,
                around: this // anchor
            });
        });
});
```

Try it and tell if any errors (untested code) :)

Comment: no idea how your layout is, this is the javascript needed. instead of ' in csjs I find all links in a webapage and bind them to mouseover ' i would suppose